# Crash after setting tool tip text in popup event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, popup, tooltip

I'm trying to dynamically set the tooltip text on select controls but keep getting crashes when the popup event is triggered. I've stripped my code back to a minimum while testing and have found the culprit to be when I set the tooltip. The crashing behaviour is the GUI will freeze and hang, become unresponsive, and shortly after will automatically close, task manager shows the process ends.

The following is the bare minimum that still crashes. Note the toolTip1 is basic with no modifications to the properties. Any controls that use the popup have a popup text of "temp" set.

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl, "test");
}
```

I did some variation and found I can get it to set the value properly on subsequent calls by using the following. It will show the "temp" text set in the designer first, and subsequent events will show "test".

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(toolTip1.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl));
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl, "test");
}
```

The above will never actually trigger the tooltip to show, just the messagebox, but it seems that setting the tooltip text is working. If I rearrange the code to set the text first as shown below, I get crashes:

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl, "test");
    MessageBox.Show(toolTip1.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl));
}
```

If I remove the SetToolTip function, the Popup event triggers fine and can run any code followed by displaying the default "temp" tooltip.

I'm not exactly sure where to go from here. I've tried a try-catch statement to return the exception message, but nothing comes back and the program continues to crash. It seems the issue is actually displaying the popup when the text is set dynamically, as I can get popups to show on controls without dynamically setting the text. (My real function has an if statement to see if the e.AssociatedControl matches one I'd like to dynamically set, any others are static. That said, I stripped my code back to the above examples with errors still)

Note this is .NET 4.8 if that's noteworthy.

Comment: When you say 'crashes' do you mean an exception is thrown? If so, can you edit your question with the exception text, and if not can you edit your question with what you mean by 'crashes'?

Comment: Crash has been clarified. I mention in the original post I've tried to catch an exception but none are thrown.

Comment: Sounds like a stack overflow is occurring in `toolTip1_Popup()`.  What framework are you using?  [tag:winforms]?  Something else?  And what happens if you only change the tooltip if necessary, e.g. `if (toolTip1.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl) != "test") toolTip1.SetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl, "test");`  Does that resolve the stack overflow?

Comment: Ah here we go, here's a duplicate for you: [WinForms: How to customize a tooltip when it is about to be shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/223220/3744182).  The answer there recommends to use a `private bool updatingTooltip;` to prevent the stack overflow.  Checking the text should work also.

Comment: Winforms with .NET 4.8. Seems checking the state before setting the text resolve the issue

Comment: It's the wrong place to `SetToolTip`. Internally, the method calls the [SetToolTipInternal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolTip.cs,d4717e75601a819a) where window, region are created based on the original text. Handlers are added/removed. Collections are modified....etc. Use this event to deal with the associated window. To resize (`e.ToolTipSize`), reposition it like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65528596/14171304). Although the duplicate answer will work, however, I would not adopt it.

Comment: Also from [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.popup?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks) _Calling properties in this event that cause the underlying window handle to be recreated, such as IsBalloon, will result in an exception being thrown._.

Comment: @dr.null - so is the answer to that other question wrong or incomplete?  Should this be reopened for a better answer?  Or should a better answer be added to that old question?

Comment: @dbc No sir, It's a good workaround I'd say. As for the reopen, I don't know, your call. I have nothing to add except the tooltip text should be set before the Popup event.

Comment: @dr.null - In that case it's probably best to not reopen thanks.